# Xcode 6.4- Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, x86-64, xcode6.4

When using Xcode 6.4 I am getting the following error for an app that used to compile

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

Attached is the settings I have used to try and fix issue but had no success

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: OK so where are the `MenuDrinkItem` and `StatusOpenOrderCell` objects defined?  Are those objects being linked in?  (look at the build log to see what's being compiled/linked).

Comment: StatusViewController.m - StatusOpenOrderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"statusOpenOrderItem"];

Comment: Check that the .m files for the two classes mentioned are included in your target

Comment: @RichTolley appears that the files are included

Comment: The code in your comment **uses** a `StatusOpenOrderCell` object but I think the important information is where its class is implemented.  The list of Compile Sources you show does't contain StatusOpenOrderCell.m or MenuDrinkItem.m, which would be the natural places.  Is the implementation somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me

In build phase go to compile resources and add menu drink item.m file

Comment: What "menu drink item.m" file are you talking about?  Do you have the same project as the OP?

Comment: lol No! from your error it is saying. Add the code that is bringing this error so I can make you understand better.

menuDrinkItem what ever it is but ,it is not compiling for some reason.
In my case I have copied my project files twice in the project folder . and compiler was unable to find the actual file and that file was the view controller class.